# Realm Many-to-One relationship example

Tags: ios, swift, realm

According to the [docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#relationships), a many to one relationship is done this way:

Assuming A is holding many of B and B is having one relationship to A

```
class B: Object {
   @objc dynamic var a: A? 
}

class A: Object {
   let bs = LinkingObjects(fromType: B.self, property: "a")
}

let a = A()
let b = B()
b.a = a
```

This sets `b.a` and `a.bs` now has one item. It works well, but I'm not able to append to A's `bs` property. What I essentially want is a linked object like it is now, but I also want to be able to created relationships the other way around like this:

```
let a = A()
let b = B()
a.bs.append(b)
```

Essentially appending a.bs will set b.a to this a that we change.
Is there any way to have linked properties like that?

## Example

Let's assume we have an Album and an Album has Songs. One Album has many songs but one song only has one album.

```
class Album : Object {
  let songs = LinkingObjects(fromType: Song.self, property: "album")
}

class Song : Object {
  @objc dynamic var album: Album?
}
```

Setting `song.album = album` works well and songs are being appended to album.songs, however appending `album.songs.append(song)` does not work.

Any idea how I can solve this? Because in the following scenario:

```
class Album : Object {
  let songs = List<Song>()
}

class Song : Object {
  @objc dynamic var album: Album?
}
```

Setting `song.album = album` will not add the song to the songs list. However in this case I can append `album.songs` but it will also not set the relationship `song.album`

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You want to set up a LinkingObjects property in "Song".

```
class Album : Object {
  @objc dynamic var name = ""
  let songs = List<Song>()
}

class Song : Object {
  @objc dynamic var name = ""
  let album = LinkingObjects(fromType: Album.self, property: "songs")
}
```

You can then create an album and append a song.

```
let album = Album()
album.name = "album1"
let song = Song()
song.name = "song1"
album.songs.append(song)

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(album)
}
```

If you want to link an existing song to another album (new or existing), fetch the song and call `album.songs.append(fetchedSong)`.

Regarding the comment about "a list of albums", LinkingObjects is an Array. You can link a song named "song1" to "album1" and "album10", for example. If you call `print(song1.album)`, you will get something like this.

```
LinkingObjects<Album> <0x7fd5c440ef10> (
[0] Album {
    name = album1;
    songs = List<Song> <0x600001b1c000> (
        [0] Song {
            name = song1;
        }
    );
},
[1] Album {
    name = album10;
    songs = List<Song> <0x600001b1c090> (
        [0] Song {
            name = song1;
        }
    );
}
```

)

You can learn about LinkingObjects and inverse relationships here: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#inverse-relationships

Comment: But then I can not set `song.album = someAlbum`. also album will not be of type Album, but of a list of albums

Comment: You don't need to set `song.album = someAlbum`. LinkingObjects takes care of that. And, yes, you can store a list of albums. I will update the answer shortly.